# Как разбить вывод ArrayList в разные ListView или SlidingTabs?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, arraylist

Недавно начал изучать android. Пилю свой пробный проект. Суть такова: тянутся статейки с сайта, с разными категориями (Новости, статьи, и т.д.), реализовываю через `SlidingTabs`, в каждом `Tab` будет своя категория. Наткнулся на такую сложность.

Есть один `ArrayList<Article>`, в `class Article` есть поле `category`. 
Задача: если `category = "Новости"` нужно вывести в `ListView` (`Tab` "Новости") все элементы с данным значением, и т.д.

Может пример есть какой (я пока что не нашел), или подскажите в какую сторону копать, в сторону `Adapter` или самого `ListView`.

Дополню.
Делается парсинг `Json` в `ArrayList`, **пример кода**:

```
try {
        JSONArray arrayArticle = response.getJSONArray("posts");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayArticle.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currentArticle = arrayArticle.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = currentArticle.getInt("id");
            String title = currentArticle.getString("title");
            String thumbnail = currentArticle.getString("thumbnail");
            String date = currentArticle.getString("date");
            String content = currentArticle.getString("content");
            JSONObject categoryObject = currentArticle.getJSONObject("categories");
            String categoryArticle = null;
            if (categoryObject.has("Новости")) {
                categoryArticle = "Новости";
            }

            Article article = new Article();
            article.setId(id);
            article.setTitle(title);
            article.setThumbnailUrl(thumbnail);
            article.setDate(date);
            article.setContent(content);
            article.setCategory(categoryArticle);
            listArticle.add(article);

        }
```

Потом делаю вывод в `Tab` полученного списка, **пример кода**:

```
private String[] categoryTabs = {"Новости", "Статьи", "Юрисдикции", "События в мире",
                            "Аналитика", "Интересное"};
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerBlogs);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter());

    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.slidingTabBlogs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
}

class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return categoryTabs.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return object == view;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return categoryTabs[position];
    }
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs, container, false);
        container.addView(view);
        listViewArticleFragment = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listArticleFragment);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), listArticle);
        listViewArticleFragment.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
```

И вот в выводе нужно чтобы элементы `ArrayList` с категорией "Новости" выводились в `Tab` "Новости". И так далее. Думал делать отдельными листами но это очень много кода. И считаю что будет не правильно.

Comment: Желательно показать немного кода. И, насколько я понял, вы с того конца смотрите. Когда переключаете на Tab "новости", делаете выборку из базы данных, где category == Новости. Ну, или, если у вас один ArrayList объектов Article, то придется циклом бегать по всему списку каждый раз:)

Comment: Для таких вещей наиболее подходит база данных, contentprovider и оборачивание данных бд в объекты, если есть такая сильная необходимость.Конкретно я сейчас для хранения данных во всех новых проектах испрльзую ORM [Realm](http://realm.io), чего и всем советую.

Comment: @pavlofff Я статьи паршу через Json в ArrayList. Тоисть лучше сделать что бы статьи заливались в базу, а потом из нее отображать?

Comment: после парсинга разбить полученный список на несколько списков по критерию category. В чем проблема, я не понимаю.

Comment: @metalurgus Проблема в отсутствии опыта. Искал в интернете, нашел пару советов ковырять `Adapter`. Попробую Ваш совет.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй рассортировать элементы в HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Article>> articleMap = new HashMap<>();

    try {
        JSONArray arrayArticle = response.getJSONArray("posts");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayArticle.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currentArticle = arrayArticle.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = currentArticle.getInt("id");
            String title = currentArticle.getString("title");
            String thumbnail = currentArticle.getString("thumbnail");
            String date = currentArticle.getString("date");
            String content = currentArticle.getString("content");
            JSONObject categoryObject = currentArticle.getJSONObject("categories");
            String categoryArticle = null;
            if (categoryObject.has("Новости")) {
                categoryArticle = "Новости";
            }

            Article article = new Article();
            article.setId(id);
            article.setTitle(title);
            article.setThumbnailUrl(thumbnail);
            article.setDate(date);
            article.setContent(content);
            article.setCategory(categoryArticle);

            ArrayList<Article> categorizedArticles = articleMap.get(article.category);
            if (categorizedArticles == null) {
                categorizedArticles = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            categorizedArticles.add(article);
            articleMap.put(article.category, categorizedArticles);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

И вытаскивай нужный тебе ArrayList по названию категории.

```
ArrayList<Article> myArticles = articleMap.get(categoryTabs[position]);
```